# Protocols in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between `id` and `id<NSObject>`. Isn't the `<NSObject>` redundant as every object conforms to this protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Id is an instance of *any* class, not necessarily one that inherits from the NSObject class. Unlike Java's Object, NSObject isn't the "one true base class" from which every class inherits. So no, not all objects conform to the NSObject protocol, meaning the `<NSObject>` isn't redundant.